# How do i know ssl is being used in mysql replication?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ssl, replication

I have successfully set up my certificates and keys and using the mysql documentation found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-ssl.html

My replication is working but i need a way to be sure if ssl is being used, how do i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

- Use Network Monitor or Wireshark, or similar, to monitor the network traffic. You will be able to see if it is TLS or not.
- Turn up the logging level till it reports the TLS negotiation.

Comment: Thanks going to use wireshark.